# Loop will not delete or remove the content from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to empty the information from a cell using the following loops where it equals a certain value. The loop seems to be working fine, however it is not executing anything. I am rather new to VBA, so I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong. I basically need the loop to go through the column and empty any cell that is equal to "Decline to state" OR does not equal "FEMALE" or "MALE". If someone may please give me some advise I would appreciate it thank you.

```
Dim g As Integer
g = 2

'Do Until IsEmpty(Range("AI" & g).Value) = True

'If Worksheets(1).Range("AI" & g).Value <> "FEMALE" Or "Male" Then
'    Worksheets(1).Range("AI" & g).Value = ""
'   End If
'g = g + 1
'Loop

Do Until IsEmpty(Range("AI" & g).Value) = True

If Cells("AI" & g).Value <> "FEMALE" Or "Male" Then
    Cells("AI" & g).Formula = ""
    End If
g = g + 1
Loop

'Do Until IsEmpty(Range("AI" & g).Value) = True

'If Worksheets(1).Range("AI" & g).Value = "DECLINE TO STATE" Then
'    Worksheets(1).Range("AI" & g).Formula = ""
'    End If
'g = g + 1
'Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. You need to use `And`, not `Or`.
2. In VBA, the left-hand side of the condition (`Cells("AI" & g).Value`) must be repeated.
3. If a cell contains the value "Decline to state", then it is *already* neither "FEMALE" nor "male". Just that logic is necessary then.

```
If Cells("AI" & g).Value <> "FEMALE" And Cells("AI" & g).Value <> "Male" Then
```

Side note: you could probably use `Range.AutoFilter` here and completely avoid looping.